Azure Logic App - how to deal with empty/missing array
Trying to load some data into a db table via Logic APP.
Using an API to make an HTTP request, parse the body and then load the data.
Issue starts when some of the arrays are either null and or missing.
How can I deal with these exemptions?
Example 1:
The below is the full body of a response. Works well.
  {
  "data": {
    "id": "36a",
    "type": "x",
    "attributes": {
      "transactionHistoryDetails": [
        {
          "accountId": "12",
          "transactions": [
            {
              "status": "Booked",
              "creditDebitIndicator": "Credit",
              "transactionId": "22",
              "transactionInformation": "Testing",
              "bookingDateTime": "2024-08-15T12:52:40+01:00",
              "valueDateTime": "2024-08-15T01:00:00+01:00",
              "amount": {
                "amount": 10.54,
                "currency": "GBP"
              },
              "balance": {
                "creditDebitIndicator": "Credit",
                "type": "InterimBooked",
                "amount": {
                  "amount": 122.67,
                  "currency": "GBP"
                }
              }
            }
 ]
        }
      ],
      "moreAvailable": false
    }
  }
}

Sometimes I get the below response instead:
Therefore missing the entire "transactionHistoryDetails" array.
{
  "data": {
    "id": "45",
    "type": "x",
    "attributes": {}
  }
}

Example 2:
A different call but similar issue
The full body output
{
  "data": {
    "id": "c80",
    "type": "x",
    "attributes": {
      "balanceDetails": [
        {
          "accountId": "203",
          "balances": [
            {
              "creditDebitIndicator": "Credit",
              "type": "Expected",
              "amount": {
                "amount": 16.45,
                "currency": "GBP"
              },
              "dateTime": "2024-08-15T14:03:42+01:00",
              "creditLine": [
                {
                  "included": false,
                  "type": "Pre-Agreed",
                  "amount": {
                    "amount": 100,
                    "currency": "GBP"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}

Some responses don't have the "creditLine" array as below:
{
  "data": {
    "id": "cb2",
    "type": "x",
    "attributes": {
      "balanceDetails": [
        {
          "accountId": "33",
          "balances": [
            {
              "creditDebitIndicator": "Credit",
              "type": "Expected",
              "amount": {
                "amount": 10.12,
                "currency": "GBP"
              },
              "dateTime": "2024-08-15T14:03:41+01:00"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}


Sorry but you need to be more specific. “Deal with them” how? Do you want to check if they exist?

If you are using the same parse JSON action for both the examples then you need to use the given schema which would work for null and empty arrays.
{
    "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
        "data": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
                "id": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "type": {
                    "type": "string"
                },
                "attributes": {
                    "type": "object",
                    "properties": {
                        "transactionHistoryDetails": {
                            "type": [
                                "array",
                                "null"
                            ],
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "accountId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "transactions": {
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "status": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "creditDebitIndicator": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "transactionId": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "transactionInformation": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "bookingDateTime": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "format": "date-time"
                                                },
                                                "valueDateTime": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "format": "date-time"
                                                },
                                                "amount": {
                                                    "type": "object",
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "amount": {
                                                            "type": "number"
                                                        },
                                                        "currency": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "balance": {
                                                    "type": "object",
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "creditDebitIndicator": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "type": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        },
                                                        "amount": {
                                                            "type": "object",
                                                            "properties": {
                                                                "amount": {
                                                                    "type": "number"
                                                                },
                                                                "currency": {
                                                                    "type": "string"
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "balanceDetails": {
                            "type": [
                                "array",
                                "null"
                            ],
                            "items": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                    "accountId": {
                                        "type": "string"
                                    },
                                    "balances": {
                                        "type": "array",
                                        "items": {
                                            "type": "object",
                                            "properties": {
                                                "creditDebitIndicator": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "type": {
                                                    "type": "string"
                                                },
                                                "amount": {
                                                    "type": "object",
                                                    "properties": {
                                                        "amount": {
                                                            "type": "number"
                                                        },
                                                        "currency": {
                                                            "type": "string"
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                },
                                                "dateTime": {
                                                    "type": "string",
                                                    "format": "date-time"
                                                },
                                                "creditLine": {
                                                    "type": [
                                                        "array",
                                                        "null"
                                                    ],
                                                    "items": {
                                                        "type": "object",
                                                        "properties": {
                                                            "included": {
                                                                "type": "boolean"
                                                            },
                                                            "type": {
                                                                "type": "string"
                                                            },
                                                            "amount": {
                                                                "type": "object",
                                                                "properties": {
                                                                    "amount": {
                                                                        "type": "number"
                                                                    },
                                                                    "currency": {
                                                                        "type": "string"
                                                                    }
                                                                }
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            }
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        "moreAvailable": {
                            "type": "boolean"
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            "required": [
                "id",
                "type"
            ]
        }
    },
    "required": [
        "data"
    ]
}

This will satisfy all the scenarios and then you need to use Conditions action for empty or null cases before loading the data to the table.
If you intend to use two different parse JSON action for the two examples then use the given schemas.
Schema for example 1-
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "string" },
        "type": { "type": "string" },
        "attributes": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "transactionHistoryDetails": {
              "type": ["array", "null"],
              "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "accountId": { "type": "string" },
                  "transactions": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "status": { "type": "string" },
                        "creditDebitIndicator": { "type": "string" },
                        "transactionId": { "type": "string" },
                        "transactionInformation": { "type": "string" },
                        "bookingDateTime": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
                        "valueDateTime": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
                        "amount": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "amount": { "type": "number" },
                            "currency": { "type": "string" }
                          }
                        },
                        "balance": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "creditDebitIndicator": { "type": "string" },
                            "type": { "type": "string" },
                            "amount": {
                              "type": "object",
                              "properties": {
                                "amount": { "type": "number" },
                                "currency": { "type": "string" }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            },
            "moreAvailable": { "type": "boolean" }
          },
          "required": ["moreAvailable"]
        }
      },
      "required": ["id", "type"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["data"]
}

Schema for example 2-
{
  "$schema": "http://json-schema.org/draft-07/schema#",
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "data": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": { "type": "string" },
        "type": { "type": "string" },
        "attributes": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "balanceDetails": {
              "type": ["array", "null"],
              "items": {
                "type": "object",
                "properties": {
                  "accountId": { "type": "string" },
                  "balances": {
                    "type": "array",
                    "items": {
                      "type": "object",
                      "properties": {
                        "creditDebitIndicator": { "type": "string" },
                        "type": { "type": "string" },
                        "amount": {
                          "type": "object",
                          "properties": {
                            "amount": { "type": "number" },
                            "currency": { "type": "string" }
                          }
                        },
                        "dateTime": { "type": "string", "format": "date-time" },
                        "creditLine": {
                          "type": ["array", "null"],
                          "items": {
                            "type": "object",
                            "properties": {
                              "included": { "type": "boolean" },
                              "type": { "type": "string" },
                              "amount": {
                                "type": "object",
                                "properties": {
                                  "amount": { "type": "number" },
                                  "currency": { "type": "string" }
                                }
                              }
                            }
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    }
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "required": ["id", "type"]
    }
  },
  "required": ["data"]
}

